# Python - using os.subprocess to call a shell script with nested commands

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, openfoam

I'm utilizing python to run a top level genetic algorithm to optimize 3D aircraft wing geometry for aerodynamic performance using OpenFOAM. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.6, and OpenFOAM 5. I have written several shell scripts that reside in the OpenFOAM case directory (directory containing geometry STL files, fluid dynamic parameters, and mesh). These scripts execute repetitive file management commands and OpenFOAM parallel process decomposition programs, along with commands that generate the 3D mesh and run the simulation. The python script should be in a different directory entirely because hundreds (if not thousands) of these case folders will be generated as offspring of the genetic algorithm. The problem is that using os.subprocess to call these shell scripts seems to generate and terminate a shell for each command in the script. For instance, if my code is (brief version):

```
#!/bin/bash
rm constant/polyMesh/*
rm constant/triSurface/*.eMesh
rm -rf 0.*
find -type d -name '*e-0*' -exec rm -r {} +
decomposePar (OpenFOAM utility)
```

and I call said script with:

```
subprocess.Popen(['./shellScript'],cwd=r'./pathToDirectory')
```

I end up getting the error:

```
./shellScript: line #: decomposePar no such file or directory
```

The only way I can see this happening if the shell is attempting to execute `decomposePar` in a directory other than the case directory (where it should go off without a hitch). For the case management commands, only the first command seems to work. I've scraped stack overflow for a solution to this problem but I'm not sure that I've found one. I've tried to set the working directory of the python script using `os.chdir('casePath')`, setting the `cwd='casePath'`, and several other `subprocess` arguments that I don't quite understand!

I know that I can just transcribe each shell command into Python, but I find it will be extremely tedious due to the number of shell commands and the potential for change to these shell scripts in the future. I'd like my method to be modular and robust enough to run only a couple of these scripts that I can modify to my needs. Additionally, at the end of the day this program will be deployed to a supercomputer. Parallel processing will happen at the C++ level in OpenFOAM, not python, so this is not one of my concerns. Is there any way to do this and am I missing something painfully obvious? Bear with me as computer science is not my strength, I am an aerospace engineer. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you need `r''` and subprocess.Popen you don't need `./` it should be a list of the first argument being the executable  `Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])`

Comment: Can you provide some real code rather than the pseudocode?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor for more information. Your case you should need ```subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh', 'shellScript']) ```

Comment: @jackotonye I've update my post

Comment: Where is the `decomposePar` located you should use `os.getcwd()` `os.chdir()` ```wd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir("/")
subprocess.Popen("ls")
os.chdir(wd)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: source the`bashrc` from the OpenFOAM installation at the start of the shell script.

After some digging with the OP the issue was initially that the directory containing `decomposePar` was not in the `PATH` environment variable.

Unless you have `.` in your PATH (this is very dangerous, do not do this), changing the current directory to the directory will not have any impact of finding `decomposePar`. Adding the full path to `decomposePar` in the shell script allowed  `decomposePar` to be run.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm constant/polyMesh/*
rm constant/triSurface/*.eMesh
rm -rf 0.*
find -type d -name '*e-0*' -exec rm -r {} +
/full/path/to/decomposePar
```

However, when being run it was unable to load the shared libraries it needed because the OpenFOAM shared libraries directory weren't in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. To fix this, the OpenFOAM `bashrc` file was sourced at the beginning of the script.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /path/to/bashrc
rm constant/polyMesh/*
...
```

Sorting this file set the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables correctly.

Comment: I have tried adding `./` and get the exact same result. Additionally, running decomposePar inside the case directory works just fine at the command line. Are you saying that if I add it to the path env variable it will be able to execute inside of the case directory?

Comment: To rule out path related issues, you could try using the full path in the script and see if that works, then work backwards.

Comment: Using the full path in the command to Popen yields the same result. With the additionally multiple lines of `tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified`

Comment: @denbjornen505 Sorry is that a question or are you saying that is what you are currently doing? If it is a question, no, I mean in the shell script itself. For example if you can change the last line in your example to `/full/path/to/decomposePar`.

Comment: when using the full path in the script: /opt/openfoam5/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/bin/decomposePar now it is executing decomposePar. But some utilities the decomposePar executes are now complaining (same error)

Comment: Is it really the same error? (i.e `decomposePar no such file or directory`) or is it complaining that some other file cannot be found?

Comment: Sorry I did not clarify. You are correct, some other file is complaining (not decomposePar): `error while loading shared libraries: libdynamicMesh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: This sounds like your LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't have the path to the libraries you need in when running via your python script. I have never used (or heard of) OpenFOAM, but you must have some things set in your environment when you normally run the tools by hand that are missing in the environment when executing via Python. Looking at some docs, there should be a bashrc file that is in your OpenFOAM installation which will set various things like that LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If you can find it, you could `source` it at the top of your shell script.

Comment: I think I've tracked down the library path you mention, containing a ton of ".so" files, including the one that threw the error. The path is: `/opt/openfoam5/platforms/linux64GccDPInt32Opt/lib`. Now I've tried to `source` this directory in my script but its telling me that it is a "directory." This is all new to me and a really appreciate your help. How can I properly source it?

Comment: Is there a file named `bashrc` anywhere in the OpenFOAM directories? If you can find that, try adding `source path/to/bashrc` after the `#!/bin/bash` line.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! That worked like a charm. Any way you could post a summary so I can give you credit for the answer! Again thanks for your patience and help

Comment: No problem, glad it worked. I have updated the answer to summarise the solution.